# Relationships overview with some many-to-many

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relations

Good morning/afternoon,

I am currently beginning a new project and I wanted to design the database before doing anything however I struggle a lot with this design because it has some many-to-many relationships and I don't know how to assemble everything nicely.

Here is the design I came up with:
[image: database design]

Here are the relationships I'm trying to achieve:
A project is linked to 0 or MULTIPLE hosts
A host is linked to ONLY 1 project
A host is linked to 0 or MULTIPLE services
A host is linked to 0 or MULTIPLE vulnerabilities
A service is linked to 1 or MULTIPLE hosts (it is ALWAYS linked to a host)
A service is linked to 0 or MULTIPLE vulnerabilities
A vulnerability is linked to 1 or MULTIPLE hosts (it is ALWAYS linked to a host)
A vulnerability is linked to 0 or MULTIPLE services
A credential is linked to 1 or MULTIPLE hosts (it is ALWAYS linked to a host)
A credential is linked to 0 or MULTIPLE service

Is my table HostDetails suitable for that job or will it be a nightmare to retrieve/insert/update data ?

What would you do to fulfill the job ?

Thank you very much for your help !

---

If you want to reproduce the schema, go to [dbdiagram.io](https://dbdiagram.io/d) and paste de following code:

```
// > many-to-one; < one-to-many; - one-to-one

Table Projects as U {
  project_id int [pk, increment] // auto-increment
  uuid uuid
  name varchar(100)
  description varchar(255)
  start_date date
  finish_date date
}

Table Hosts {
  host_id int [pk, increment]
  host_uuid uuid
  ip_address inet
  mac_address macaddr
  status smallint
  operating_system varchar(50)
  usage varchar(50)
  project_id int [ref: > Projects.project_id]
}

Table Services {
  service_id int [pk, increment]
  service_uuid uuid
  port smallint
  protocol varchar(5)
  service varchar(50)
  version varchar(50)
  status smallint
 }

Table HostsCredentials {
  credential_id int [pk, increment]
  credential_uuid uuid
  username varchar(50)
  password varchar(50)
  hash varchar(255)
 }

Table HostsDetails {
  host_detail_id int [pk, increment]
  host_id int [ref: > Hosts.host_id]
  service_id int [ref: > Services.service_id]
  vulnerability_id int [ref: > Vulnerabilites.vulnerability_id]
  credential_id int [ref: > HostsCredentials.credential_id]
 }

Table Vulnerabilites {
  vulnerability_id int [pk, increment]
  vulnerability_uuid uuid
  cvss_vector varchar(50)
  status smallint
  description text
  evidence text
  solution text
  references text
}
```

Comment: It looks a little like a star schema.  Is that the intent?

Comment: @WalterMitty absolutely not haha I think I need to break down the HostsDetails table into multiple tables in order to make M:N relationships between the tables I want.